# How to prevent Spring from creating a new server with every run(Embedded server)

Tags: java, spring

Every time I run; it creates a server with a new port.
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8088 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8088 or configure this application to listen on another port.

run without create new server

Comment: if you are using `spring-boot`, try having `server.port=0` in your properties file

Comment: Spring is used to run a server. A serer needs a port. Stop the earilier app or check how to change the port of your app using a appliation.properties or appliation.yml file or environment property to specify a different port

Comment: " it creates a server with a new port. " but a port can be used by one app at a time only. so you must stop the other app or change the port your app is running on. Most IDEs will help you run app only once at a time. if from commandline you can use ps tools

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Spring Boot application to start on a random available port each time it runs, you can configure it to use a dynamic port. This is particularly useful when you want to avoid port conflicts, especially when running multiple instances of your application concurrently.

Open your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file and add the following line:

```
server.port=0
```

Setting the `server.port` property to `0` instructs Spring Boot to choose a random available port when starting the application.